# MPAndroidChart - Round corners on stacked bars

Tags: java, android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I need to create a chart with stacked bars and the bars need to be rounded. So far, I've succeeded in making the bars rounded, but if they're not stacked. If stacked, then each bar is rounded, which is something I don't need. I need the bar to be rounded regardless if it is stacked or not.

Here's how it should look:
[image: stacked_rounded]

And here's how it looks at the moment: [image: stacked_not]

I've made my custom renderer and overriden the `drawDataSet` method, but I can't figure out how to round the top and bottom regardless of the stacks.

```
 @Override
protected void drawDataSet(Canvas c, IBarDataSet dataSet, int index) {

    Transformer trans = mChart.getTransformer(dataSet.getAxisDependency());

    mShadowPaint.setColor(dataSet.getBarShadowColor());

    float phaseX = mAnimator.getPhaseX();
    float phaseY = mAnimator.getPhaseY();


    // initialize the buffer
    BarBuffer buffer = mBarBuffers[index];
    buffer.setPhases(phaseX, phaseY);
    buffer.setDataSet(index);
    buffer.setBarWidth(mChart.getBarData().getBarWidth());
    buffer.setInverted(mChart.isInverted(dataSet.getAxisDependency()));

    buffer.feed(dataSet);

    trans.pointValuesToPixel(buffer.buffer);

    // if multiple colors
    if (dataSet.getColors().size() > 1) {

        for (int j = 0; j < buffer.size(); j += 4) {

            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(buffer.buffer[j + 2]))
                continue;

            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(buffer.buffer[j]))
                break;

            if (mChart.isDrawBarShadowEnabled()) {
                if (mRadius > 0)
                    c.drawRoundRect(new RectF(buffer.buffer[j], mViewPortHandler.contentTop(),
                            buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                            mViewPortHandler.contentBottom()), mRadius, mRadius, mShadowPaint);
                else
                    c.drawRect(buffer.buffer[j], mViewPortHandler.contentTop(),
                            buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                            mViewPortHandler.contentBottom(), mShadowPaint);
            }

            // Set the color for the currently drawn value. If the index
            // is
            // out of bounds, reuse colors.
            int size = dataSet.getStackSize();
            mRenderPaint.setColor(dataSet.getColor(j / 4));
            if (mRadius > 0) {
                RectF customRect = new RectF(buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 3]);
                Path path = roundRect(customRect, 25f, 25f, true, true, false, false);
                c.drawPath(path, mRenderPaint);
            } else
                c.drawRect(buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 3], mRenderPaint);
        }
    } else {

        mRenderPaint.setColor(dataSet.getColor());

        for (int j = 0; j < buffer.size(); j += 4) {

            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(buffer.buffer[j + 2]))
                continue;

            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(buffer.buffer[j]))
                break;

            if (mChart.isDrawBarShadowEnabled()) {
                if (mRadius > 0)
                    c.drawRoundRect(new RectF(buffer.buffer[j], mViewPortHandler.contentTop(),
                            buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                            mViewPortHandler.contentBottom()), mRadius, mRadius, mShadowPaint);
                else
                    c.drawRect(buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                            buffer.buffer[j + 3], mRenderPaint);
            }

            if (mRadius > 0)
                c.drawRoundRect(new RectF(buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 3]), mRadius, mRadius, mRenderPaint);
            else
                c.drawRect(buffer.buffer[j], buffer.buffer[j + 1], buffer.buffer[j + 2],
                        buffer.buffer[j + 3], mRenderPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @EmreAydemir nope, there was no solution, I implemented the charts by myself instead of using the library.

Comment: Can you share your solution with me?

Comment: @EmreAydemir unfortunately no, it was for a previous company I worked for, so don't have the code. :(